# Getting objects from a table for a given condition for the field in another table

Tags: linq

Let's say I have two tables. The first one is `Models` that has `Id`, `MachineType`, `BrandId` and `ModelName` columns, the second table is `Brands` with `Id` and `BrandName` columns.

I need to write a method for my repository that returns all brands for a given MachineType. If I'd have had a column MachineType in the Brands table, it'd have been pretty simple:

```
    public IEnumerable<Brand> GetBrandByType(MachineTypeEnum type)
    {
        return _context.Brands.Where(x => x.MachineType == type).AsEnumerable();
    }
```

But how to do it in my case?

Comment: How is Brand related to MachineType?

Comment: Brand can have several MachineTypes. For example, the brand is KOMATSU, MachineTypes are excavators, bulldozers, etc.

Comment: Right, but how are they related in the database?  Is there a many to many relationship through a relating table for example?

Comment: Actually, there is no any relationship between them. lazyberezovsky's solution works well.

Comment: So MachineType is a Varchar on the Brand table?

Comment: There is no MachineType in Brands table, MachineType is in Models table and it is Enum type in the EF data model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have navigation properties defined on your entities:

```
_context.Brands.Where(b => b.Models.Any(m => m.MachineType == type))
        .AsEnumerable();
```

Otherwise

```
from b in _context.Brands
join m in _context.Models
     on b.Id equals m.BrandId into g   
where g.Any(m => m.MachineType == type)
select b
```

Comment: Will up vote when the OP is clear about what he is asking if this is the correct answer.